# Notepad ++ not recognizing R language

Tags: r, notepad++

I was reviewing a .rmd file of a colleague for an R script today and realized the style functionality was not working.  I am new to this way of R coding and so wanted it in what I am used to reading and so renamed the script a .r so that the style functionality would be enabled.

The style format appeared but then I realized at some point it was no longer working again. Now I can't get Notepad++ to recognize my R scripts (those with a .r in the file naming convention) and can't figure out why.

Should R be a choice in the language selection drop down menu?

When I go to -> Settings -> Style Configurator the recent Style is selected but the colors for the comments (for instance) don't match. They should be green and they are not. I am using Notepadd++ 6.5.5. I would update but our IT department makes it very difficult to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1.Check if checkbox **Enable Global foreground colour** is off in settings -> -> Style Configurator -> global stylers -> global override .
2.Try changing color theme.
3.Check **R**'s lang syntax colors in Style Configurator.

Comment: This initially worked but i noticed the changes were not reflected in the other scripts i had open in Notepad++.  I closed the program and when i reopened it the style configuration was back to not showing the format, even for the script that had the changes.  I have used Notepad++ for 7+ years and have never faced any of these challenges.  This is strange.  I am currently using the Zenburn theme with R selected in the language.

Comment: I found that for some reason i need to reload all the scripts or rename them .txt and then .r files in order to get Notepad++ to employ the style configuration, a truly strange situation.  I think it might have something to do with loading the initial script which was a .rmd file.

Comment: @JoshR. I think in newer builds that fixed.

Comment: Going to the "Language" tab and choosing "R" solved it for me.

Answer (score 38):

Remove R key from REBOL section in the file ‘langs.xml’ (path: user\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\langs.xml )

Line 301 by default is:

```
<Language name=“rebol” ext=" r reb" commentLine=";" commentStart="" commentEnd="">
```

The messed up part is ext=" r reb". It should just say ext=“reb”
Change that, save the file and you are all set.

See:

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/14363/r-file-association-messed-up

Comment: mine was called langs.model.xml, not langs.xml

Comment: that fixes .R files being autorecognized as Rebol source, but syntax highlighting still doesnt work